# Webpack can't load the json file, how to locate the local json file and load that using http.get with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ecmascript-6, webpack

I am using AngularJs of ES6 syntax, I am trying to load a local themes.json file from ApiService.js

```
  getThemesOptions() {
    this.$http.get('src/app-builder/p3-modal/themes.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .error(function() {

    });
```

My file structure:

```
src/
  app-builder/
    p3-modal/
      themes.json
  service/
    apiService/
       apiService.js
```

From the console, looks like it found the file successfully, but the output is very strange,

[image]

Because themes.json looks like this:[image]

I am running the application using Webpack, the url to access the application is not normally localhost, but http://10.98.142.233:8080/o2/search/ab instead, I don't know what cause the problem

Please tell me how to load the json file from local correctly , using AngularJs ES6 with webpack.

Thanks!

This is the network tab.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, actually what happens is it *can't* find the JSON file, and the Webpack dev server routes the 404 back to your index.html, which is what you're seeing in the console. The success callback fires because technically, it's not a 404 but a 200 OK.

What you're doing should work so long as the Webpack dev server is serving content from the directory immediately above the src folder. I'm guessing that might not be the case.

Comment: Please advice how do I get the themes.json file in this case..... stuck at this for hours, I tried as you suggested before, put at root folder, it doesn't work.

Comment: Check the network tab in the developers tools to see the request for the JSON file. It might provide some clues. Also, make sure that the src folder is actually in your app root, or use the the `--content-base` option of Webpack dev server to use a different folder if that's not the case.

Comment: setting contentbase correctly fixed mine issue.` devServer: {
    contentBase: "./src"
  }`

Answer (score 2):

your browser location is `www.google.com/image`,and then when you call an ajax the url that request to is `www.google.com/image/${url}` but if put a slash before your url would be like `/src/app..` and the url it would request to is like `www.google.com/${url}`